# Отправка формы без ведома пользователя.

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно отправлять форму на другой сайт(домен) что бы пользователь не видел. Т.е он зашел и на другой сайт отправились данные формой. Без нажатия кнопки и переадресации как?

Comment: читайте про ajax, подругому никак не получится ;)

Comment: А разве все это не завершится ошибкой доступа ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@istem](/users/1254/istem)](/users/1254/istem), не соглашусь с Вами. Политика безопасности браузера наложит ограничение лишь на получение данных, а не как на их отправку. Т.е. достаточно сделать просто ajax-запрос, и данные отправятся, браузер даже получит ответ, и тут он уже создаст исключение.
С помощью jQuery можно вот так просто отправить запрос:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://somesite.com",
  type: "POST", // для отправки GET-запроса используйте GET
  data: {param1 : "val1", param2 : "val2"},
});
```

Такой вариант подойдёт, если Вам не нужно получать ответ от удалённой стороны. Иначе же может помочь JSONP-запрос.

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax не будет работать по Same Origin Policy. В вашем случае, подходит несколько вариантов. Если метод формы GET - тогда можно через тег img или script средствами JS сформировать запрос и добавить элемент в тело документа. Второй вариант - добавить атрибут target="iframe" к форме, и соответственно сам iframe на страницу. При срабатывании DOM Ready - отправлять форму. Форма отправится, результат отобразится в iframe, а уж его можно спозиционировать: left: -9999px;

Если заинтересует - напишите подробнее что там у вас, помогу с кодом, как это сделать.

Comment: Как вариант, можно форму сабмитить на свой скрипт, а скрипт уже например через curl запросит данные с нужного сайта методом GET или POST

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onLoad="submitForm()">
<form id="fm">
...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
//JS
function submitForm()
{
   document.getElementById('fm').submit();
}

//jQuery
document.ready(function(){
   $('#fm').submit();
});

</script>
```

Я показал два варианта сабмита формы. Один - на чистом JS, другой - с использованием jQuery. При использовании jQuery, тэгу body не нужен onLoad.

Если нужна асинхронная отправка, тогда юзаем к примеру jQuery так:

```
$.get('http://site.com', {'param': 'val', 'param2': 'val2'}, function(data) {
   //result into data
});
```

либо

```
$.post('http://site.com', {'param': 'val', 'param2': 'val2'}, function(data) {
   //result into data
});
```

Comment: Мне нужно отправлять формы на другой сервер, ajax не подходит. Пользователь должен остоваться на странице моего сайта.

Comment: Чем AJAX не устраивает?

Comment: PHP головного мозга? :)

    {'param' => 'val', 'param2' => 'val2'}

Comment: Точно! :)
Прошу прощения, надо так:
{'param': 'val', 'param2': 'val2'}